# A small RSS application with predefined settings

Tags: rss

We are working on a new website ([WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress)), and we're going to publish news-articles there. We have our users in one domain, and now we want to have an RSS reader on all our clients which reads from this feed.

It has to be preconfigured by us (setting up the feed-address and how often to check for new feeds, etc.). It should only be a tray-icon which pops up when new feeds are published, with a link to the website.

Are there any existing applications? Or is there some code sample in C# on how to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom solution might be a nice idea for your client, if you like branding.

[RSS.NET](http://www.rssdotnet.com/) might be what you need.

EDIT: Actually, here is a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576267/c-rss-reader) on creating a RSS reader in C#, if you're interested.

Comment: It is, I remember in VS2005 the screen saver template project had some RSS parsing code examples too, but I figured newer up-to-date examples are better ;)